# Define a function invRunEncode which is an inverse function for RunEncode

Tags: list-manipulation

For example:

```
invRunEncode[ {{1, 3}, {2, 1}, {10, 2}, {2, 2}, {4, 2}, {3, 3}} ]
```

> ```
> {1, 1 , 1, 2, 10, 10, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3}
> ```

My solution (attempting at a pure function notation):

```
invRunEncode2 = Union[Table[Table[#n, {i, 1, Length[##n]}], {n, 1, Length[##]}]] & ;
```

It doesn't work and I think that is due to a misconception/error around the function notations.

Comment: Flatten[Table @@@#]&  would do the job

Answer (score 1):

Here is the first function

```
Flatten[Table@@@#]&@ {{1, 3}, {2, 1}, {10, 2}, {2, 2}, {4, 2}, {3, 3}}
```

> {1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 10, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3}

and here is the inverse

```
Flatten[Tally/@Split@#,1]&@ {1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 10, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3}
```

> {{1, 3}, {2, 1}, {10, 2}, {2, 2}, {4, 2}, {3, 3}}

Answer (score 1):

A variation of @J's answer using operator forms:

```
invRunEncode = Flatten @* Map[Apply[ConstantArray]];

invRunEncode[{{1,3},{2,1},{10,2},{2,2},{4,2},{3,3}}]
```

> {1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 10, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3}